# Initialise a class with objects of another class

Tags: python, class

say I have a class which describes a ball and its properties:

```
class Ball:
    def __init__(self, m=0.0,x=0.0, y=0.0):
        self.m = m
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.r = np.array([x,y])
        
    def pos(self):
        print('Current position is:', self.r)  
            
    def move(self, x_move, y_move):
        x_moved = self.x+ x_move
        y_moved = self.y+ y_move
        r_moved = ([x_moved, y_moved])
        self.r = r_moved
```

How do i create another class which would initialise with objects from class Ball?
And use methods from class Ball too?

I'm trying to create something like:

```
a = Ball(2,2,2)

class Simulation:
    def __init___('''object of Ball e.g. a''', r):

    def next_move(self):
        position_after_next_move = a.pos + '''method move from class Ball'''
```

I hope what I'm trying to say makes some sense.

Comment: Hint: "How do I create another class which would initialize with objects from class `float`? And use methods from that class too?" (You already do this: it is the class `Ball` in your example. `float` is a class. There is **nothing special** here. Voting to close because there isn't a sensible question here; the way to do what you ask is to use the same kind of code that you already show.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 2):

You are very close. You just need to pass the `ball` into the `__init__()` method and store it on the instance:

```py
class Simulation:
    def __init___(self, ball, r):
        self.ball = ball
        ...

    def next_move(self):
        position_after_next_move = self.ball.pos()

a = Ball(2,2,2)
s = Simulation(a, 42)
s.next_move()
```

Comment: I think you mean `s.next_move()`

Comment: Ok, oops ........ fixed. Thanks.